# BinarySecurityToken with wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I've successfully tested connecting to a SOAP service using SoapUI (5.1.2), and now I need to generate the soap requests from a C# application.

I added a keystore to SoapUI, where the certificate is stored, and the security configuration from SoapUI is fairly straighforward...

[image: SoapUI Screencap showing simple security settings]

And here is a working sample request (details removed)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:typ="url.removed">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
               xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
                            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" 
                            wsu:Id="X509-08AC5A2756F38141D814355761534501">    <!-- data removed --></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-08AC5A2756F38141D814355761534824" 
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap typ" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue><!-- data removed --></ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-08AC5A2756F38141D814355761534752">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference 
        wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" 
        wsu:Id="STR-08AC5A2756F38141D814355761534763" 
        xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-08AC5A2756F38141D814355761534501" 
                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>

  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <typ:SoapDataRequest>
      <header>
        <dataremoved />
      </header>
      <bodyremoved />
    </typ:SoapDataRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to programmatically create the bindings/configuration required, I already have the web reference imported into my project, just need to select the right combination from the myriad of options in wcf to get this working. If I don't provide the SSL cert required, it is an obvious error, so I know I'm fetching the certificate correctly from cert store (as opposed to *.pfx file from soupUI), but eveything else fails with "Policy Falsified", which is a security mismatch as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here to get it working for me :

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/672063/Calling-a-service-with-oasis-header-in-Csharp

using Soap 1.2 and not Soap 1.1

Comment: I assume you didn't followed all steps in the article on Codeproject. Could you be a little more specific about the solution you used please? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @Jorr.it, that was ages ago, and I don't work for that company anymore, so cant even go look in source control for you.